# Using Common Selenium WebDriver instance

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, instance

I want use a common WebDriver instance across all my TestNG tests by extending my test class to use a base class as shown below but it doesn't seem to work :

```
public class Browser {

private static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

public static WebDriver getDriver()
{
    return driver;
}
public static void open(String url)
{
    driver.get(url);
}
public static void close()
{
    driver.close();
}
}
```

I want to use the WebDriver in my test class as shown below, but I get the error message :
**The method getDriver() is undefined for the type GoogleTest**:

```
   public class GoogleTest extends Browser
   {

      @Test
      public void GoogleSearch() {
     WebElement query = getDriver().findElement(By.name("q"));
     // Enter something to search for
     query.sendKeys("Selenium");
     // Now submit the form
     query.submit();
     // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
     // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 5 seconds
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 30);
     // wait.Until((d) => { return d.Title.StartsWith("selenium"); });
     //Check that the Title is what we are expecting
     assertEquals("selenium - Google Search", getDriver().getTitle().toString());
   }
}
```

Comment: This should work. What IDE or compiler are you using? Are you sure you are referring to the right `Browser` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `getDriver` method is **static**.

Solution #1: Make method non-static (this will either need to make the `driver` variable non-static as well, or use `return Browser.getDriver();` )

```
public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver;
}
```

**Or,** call the `getDriver` method by using `Browser.getDriver`

```
WebElement query = Browser.getDriver().findElement(By.name("q"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies they all work, but I was wondering if I could use the driver variable directly i.e.                        WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

Comment: Ignore my last comment I have used simons solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your driver, one of many solution is to try @Before to add, Junit will autorun it for you.

```
    public class Browser {

        private WebDriver driver;

        @Before
        public void runDriver()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        public WebDriver getDriver()
        {
            return driver;
        }

        public void open(String url)
        {
            driver.get(url);
        }

        public void close()        
        {
            driver.close();
        }
  }
```